# Rails: javascript addEventListener does not find element in dynamic form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implement a dynamic form in a Rails App through AJAX and did a couple of tutorials, but without success.

The Javascript part from my application js file in the asset folder

```
var land = document.getElementById("cart_land_id");
land.addEventListener("change", function(){
  Rails.ajax({
    url: "/carts?land=" + land.value,
    type: "GET"
  })
})
```

For this form in a view:

```
<%= form_for @cart, :url => {:action => "show_shipping"}, :html => {:method => "get"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :land_id, options_for_select(@lands.map { |l| [l.name.titleize, l.id] }, {:id => 'lands_select', :prompt => "select a country"}) %><br>
  <%= f.select :shippingservice_id, options_for_select([]) %><br>
  <%= f.submit "Calculate shipping" %>
<% end %>
```

Which gets rendered as:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/carts/show_shipping/4" class="edit_cart" id="edit_cart_4" method="get">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>
  <select id="cart_land_id" name="cart[land_id]"><option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
  ...
  <select id="cart_shippingservice_id" name="cart[shippingservice_id]"></select><br>
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Calculate shipping" />
</form>
```

produces an

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'land.addEventListener')
```

I have jQuery in my Javascript directory.

Why does this happen and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to add listeners:

1. Add a listener to some specific element: `document.getElementById("...").addEventListener(type, fn)` or `document.querySelector("...").addEventListener(type, fn)`.
2. Add a listener to a parent element, with a matcher: `document.addEventListener(type, fn)` where `fn` checks if `event.target.closest('#cart_land_id')` exists before continuing.

In your case, having jquery helps because there is a shorthand:

```
$(document).on("change", "#cart_land_id", function(event){
  Rails.ajax({
    url: "/carts?land=" + event.target.value,
    type: "GET"
  })
})
```

The listener is set up on document (there is no other element available to target) but only the events that are bubbling from `#cart_land_id` are sent to the listener.

---

UPDATE

To make an ajax request, you can definitely use `fetch` - which is natively supported in most browsers, and can be polyfilled.

```
fetch("/carts?land=" + event.target.value).
  then(function(resp) { return resp.text(); }).
  then(function(text) {
    // do something with text
    // for instance replace the content of some element:
    someEl.innerHTML = text;
  });
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch for more info

Comment: something is finally happening. At least the on_change is recognized, but I get `Can't find variable: Rails`.

Comment: When I use `$.ajax` he starts looking and I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. In case I have a specific action in my carts controller I suppose I would have to write `url: "/carts/land=" + event.target.value,`?

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply. I will work on it and than give feedback. Do you know if the `Rails.ajax` is an error and it should be `$.ajax` right away? In case that is true could you correct it in your answer, so that we keep a clean track? Or correct me if I did something wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I never use libraries when native alternatives are available. There is no need of jQuery or any other ajax thing, `fetch` is the way to go.

Comment: I prefer native too. But somehow I get `Can't find variable: Rails`, when using `Rails.ajax` in a Rails 3 app using jquery-rails 3.1.5 + jQuery 2.2.4 in the asset pipeline. I will try to go through all the work first and than figure out why Rails.ajax does not work.

Comment: The ajax part is now working. It registers the on change event and loads a resource from the server, which is my next task. I consider this question as closed and will treasure your answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: `Rails.ajax` is not native, it's some js library. Use native `fetch` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As you have jQuery, you can use the following code

```
$("body").on("change", "#cart_land_id", function(event){
    var landValue = $("#cart_land_id").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/carts?land=" + landValue,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(response) {
            // handle response here
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I still get: `null is not an object (evaluating '$("body").on')`